# Delphi gettimeofday for OSX (equivalent for timeGetTime under win)

Tags: macos, delphi, timer, cross-platform, delphi-xe3

I am converting a threaded timer pool unit for cross platform use. 
The current unit uses timeGetTime to ensure high accuracy and to report the actual elapsed interval when the timer event is called.

I have used gettimeofday in OSX before to get a high resolution timer but cannot find any reference to it for use in Delphi XE3.

Looking for help on how I can call this in Delphi or an alternative cross platform way to get a high res timer. I want ms accuracy (I know its OS dependent) for this.

Thanks in advance, Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better option, multi-platform ready, may be to use the [`TStopWatch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch) record from the [System.Diagnostics](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Diagnostics) unit.

The TStopWatch is a true high resolution timer if available, and in that case have close to nano-second precision (depend on the OS and hardware), and if not available (in Windows) use standard timer functions to provide millisecond precision.

If you want only millisecond precision, use the ElapsedMilliseconds property, like this:

```
var
  sw : TStopWatch;
  ElapsedMilliseconds : Int64;
begin
  sw := TStopWatch.Create() ;
  try
    sw.Start;
    Whatever();
    sw.Stop;

    ElapsedMilliseconds := sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
  finally
    sw.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The TStopWatch relies on [QueryPreformanceFrequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions in windows and [mach_absolute_time](http://www.macresearch.org/tutorial_performance_and_time) on OS-X

Comment: This relies on stopping the TStopWatch before you can read the times elapsed. To use this as a high res event timer (equiv TTimer) is it safe to use the getTimeStamp function provided in the interface?

Comment: @Martin AFAIK there's no need to stop the timer to read the Elapsed values, and about GetTimeStamp, it is _safe_ but maybe is not what you expect to be. You can check how the GetTimeStamp value is used inside the record and, since it is not documented in which units the value is returned, IMHO it may change in the future. IIRC GetTimeStamp returns nanoseconds in XE3 for both, OS-X and Win32.

Comment: Interesting. You are correct that reading the Elapsed without stopping the StopWatch does work. 
The documentation however does say "The value of Elapsed is only updated if the stopwatch is priorly stopped. Reading the Elapsed property while the stopwatch is running does not yield any difference." I hope this is not "Fixed" in the future.